# where is the definition for related syntax in core.schema file?

Tags: ldap, openldap

When reading openldap's shema file "core.schema", there are some question:

1. In the following code, What's meaning of SUP?

Is it mean superior type? If true, where is the 'name' definition? I can't find the definition of name.

```
# system schema
#attributetype ( 2.5.4.3 NAME ( 'cn' 'commonName' )
#   DESC 'RFC2256: common name(s) for which the entity is known by'
#   SUP name )
```

2. Where is the definition of syntax  1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.38 ? what's the meaning and where is the definition?

```
attributetype ( 2.5.4.0 NAME 'objectClass'
DESC 'RFC2256: object classes of the entity'
EQUALITY objectIdentifierMatch
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.38 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SUP` means `superior`, as in inheritance. For example:

```
attributeTypes: ( 2.5.4.41 NAME 'name' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{32768}
  X-ORIGIN 'RFC 4519' )
```

And then:

```
attributeTypes: ( 2.5.4.3 NAME ( 'cn' 'commonName' ) SUP name
  X-ORIGIN 'RFC 4519' )
```

`cn` "inherits" from `name`, that is, `cn` is a descendent of `name`. `cn` uses the EQUALITY and SUBSTR (substring) matching rules from `name` as well as the SYNTAX in this example. For information about the OID and parameter assignments, see

- [LDAP Standards](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/standards-information.html)

On that page, the [Parameter Assignments](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ldap-parameters/ldap-parameters.xml) might be useful.